# How can I extend an image's height equidistant beyond its full-width container?

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image I'd like to extend beyond its parent container, just on the top and bottom, the same distance. I'm able to achieve this effect on the top, but am not able to do so on the bottom. How can I achieve this effect while still remaining responsive and keeping remaining content within the parent?

[image]

I've tried various methods of absolute positioning, but kept breaking the grid. I was able to achieve what I have thus far using negative margins, but only on top.

This is the very basic code I have thus far [and here's the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7k5rq4u1/):

```css
.band {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.contain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.row {
  align-content: flex-start;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: visible;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-image {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="band">
  <div class="contain">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450?text=fpo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using *negative margins* and *absolute* positioning on the image:

- use *negative margins* for the offsetting of the second column,
- using *absolute positioning* of the image in the second column ensures that the height is determined by the left column (because the `row` container is a flexbox and `align-items: stretch` is the default), and
- use `object-fit: cover` to maintain image aspect ratio.

See demo below:

```css
.band {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.contain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.row {
  align-content: flex-start;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: visible;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-image {
  margin: -20px 0 -20px 0; /* negative margin */
  position: relative;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* absolute positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="band">
  <div class="contain">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450?text=fpo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @joewindetc simplified fiddle for the above: https://jsfiddle.net/xhue8bvw/

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. And then thanks for the introduction to `object-fit`, that's a new one to me.

Answer (score 1):

Positioning seems to work

```css
.band {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.contain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.row {
  align-content: flex-start;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="band">
  <div class="contain">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x450?text=fpo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had originally started with something like this, but ran into the issue where the width of the image wouldn't adjust with the width of the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

You can also play with background of the `band` element to simulate this

```css
.band {
  background: 
    url(https://via.placeholder.com/800x450?text=fpo) calc(50% + 160px) 0/auto 100%,
    linear-gradient(#ddd,#ddd) center/100% calc(100% - 40px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.contain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  padding:40px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="band">
  <div class="contain">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this! A way I hadn't considered. Looking forward though, this image might also become a video. I'll have to add this to my toolbox regardless. Thanks!